# Carnot Cycle Question

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

I have two questions surrounding the Carnot cycle.  The typical diagram for a Carnot cycle is shown here: [image]

I have several textbooks that discuss this cycle, but what none of them do is explain how points B and D, where the process is switched from an isothermal one to an adiabatic one, is determined.

So my first question is: How does one know that at the volume represented by the point $V_D$, one ends the isothermal compression and begins the adiabatic compression?  (I guess one answer might be that it's an engine, it doesn't *choose* - it just *does its thing*?)

My second question is: What happens if you start moving $V_B$ and $V_D$ around?  For instance, suppose you move $V_D$ closer to $V_A$?  What if you make $V_D$ less than $V_A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. Where the top isothermal finishes, that is point B, is more or less arbitrary, but there has to be 'spare' unswept volume in the cylinder to allow for the adiabatic expansion BC. Point D has to be determined 'in advance'. The adiabatic curve through point D has to pass through A. If the working substance behaves like an ideal gas, this requires that
$$p_D V_D^\gamma=p_A V_A^\gamma.$$

Q2 You can't move all the points around arbitrarily. For example, if, as you suggest, you make $V_D$ less than $V_A$, you can't return from D to A along an adiabatic path!

Comment: Thanks!  I should have realized that just as there are isothermal lines there are adiabat lines.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reproduce a piston heat engine working with a Carnot cycle you have the constraints of the minimum volume $V_{min}$ and maximum volume $V_{max}$, by the top and bottom dead points of the stroke of the piston.

Then we have **two independent parameters** to determine the cycle. As an example, we can choose the temperature of the two heat reservoirs $T_{hot}$, $T_{cold}$ needed to perform isothermal transformations.

All the other parameters, as the volume where we switch from isothermal to adiabatic transformations, either on the compression stroke or on the expansion stroke are dependent variables.

In the picture below, you can show what happens as the $T_{hot}^I$ (and thus the points $B^I$ and $D^I$), keeping constant the temperature of the cold reservoir $T_{cold}$.

[image]

Now, we need to think at the realization of a Carnot cycle through a piston engine. We can realize it changing the angular velocity of the shaft, so that:

- the isothermal transformations occur extremely slowly, so that the system can exchange the heat with the external reservoir keeping its temperature constant,
- the adiabatic transformations occur extremely fast, so that the system has no time to exchange heat with the external reservoir, approximating an adiabatic transformation,

as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I have several textbooks that discuss this cycle, but what none of
> them do is explain how points B and D, where the process is switched
> from an isothermal one to an adiabatic one, is determined.

Point B is technically arbitrary and depends only at which point the system is surrounding by thermal insulation. The longer the isothermal expansion is carried out, the greater the heat transferred to the system by the hot reservoir and the greater the work done during the expansion.  The shorter it is carried out, the less the heat transfer to the system and the less the work done during the expansion. It should be noted, however, that as the external pressure decreases the amount of additional work done by the system also decreases.

> So my first question is: How does one know that at the volume
> represented by the point , one ends the isothermal compression and
> begins the adiabatic compression?

One has to end the isothermal compression at $V_D$ in order to be able to connect point D and A by a reversible adiabatic process. For that to happen the pressure and volume at D has to be related to the pressure and volume at A by

$$P_{D}V_{D}^{\gamma}=P_{A}V_{A}^{\gamma}$$

> My second question is: What happens if you start moving $V_B$ and
> $V_D$ around?  For instance, suppose you move $V_D$ closer to $V_A$?
> What if you make $V_D$ less than $V_A$?

When you move $V_D$ closer to $V_A$, or make $V_D$ less than $V_A$ you increase the heat transfer out of the system during the isothermal compression. I you perform the necessary calculations, you will find that that the additional heat loss during the isothermal compression will be greater than the additional heat added for the non adiabatic process going from D to A, for an overall reduction in net work and thermal efficiency.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Carnot's engine is steam engine, so it has two heat reservoir as source and sink keeping at constant high and low temperatures. From point C to D, cylinder is placed in contact with sink, so walls of cylinder cools down the system's gas, as process is isothermal so done slowly.

At point D, cylinder is removed from sink and placed on insulating slab. Weight is placed or increased, so surrounding can do work on the system. By placing on insulating slab, process is adiabatic so piston compress quickly to initial point of cycle, A.

What if volume at D is move closer to volume at A. Then the closed area of cycle become slightly large, so more work can be obtained from the engine. But point D can't go left to the A, because that means in adiabatic compression pressure is increasing with increasing volume without adding heat, which is not possible thermodynamically.